# Difference between this meta site and the main site

Tags: discussion, support

What is the difference between `webmasters.stackexchange.com` and `meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com`?

My reputation count is same in both accounts but other details are different. In `webmasters.stackexchange.com` my contribution in 33 questions and 27 answers but in `meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com` there is no contribution but it's showing my reputation as 541.

I need to know the difference between this two accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site (**meta**) is for questions about how the `webmasters.stackexchange.com` (the **main** site) works.  So when you asked this question, you asked it in the correct place.  If questions get asked in the wrong place, the moderators have the power to move questions between the main and meta sites.

As far as reputation goes, contributions on the meta site do not count towards your reputation.  Your reputation will remain 541, even if this question gets upvotes.  The number of upvotes that you get on the meta site is logged, but the total is not displayed anywhere. Recent upvotes are displayed when you hover over your user name at the top of the page and you can see how many votes your received "today", "this week", and "this month", but the total is not displayed.  You can also visit your meta profile and look at your questions and answers to see how many upvotes each individual question and answer has received, but there is no total added up for you.